# I need more than a row PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a PostgreSQL subquery that can return more than a row. Here's the piece of the query that I have so far:

```
select (SELECT ARRAY[url, thumb_1, thumb_200, thumb_500]
                FROM "Image"
                LEFT JOIN "Product_Image"
                ON "Image".id = "Product_Image".image_id
                WHERE "Product_Image".product_id = 517
                ORDER BY "Product_Image".sort ASC) as images
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the subquery in the `FROM` clause?

```
select vals
from (SELECT ARRAY[url, thumb_1, thumb_200, thumb_500] as vals
      FROM "Image" LEFT JOIN
           "Product_Image"
           ON "Image".id = "Product_Image".image_id
      WHERE "Product_Image".product_id = 517
     ) images
```